# Windows 7 - "New Program" highlight won't go away

Tags: windows-7

I had one of the Help Desk guys install a program on my machine.  I have a Windows 7 Machine, which has the feature that when a new program is installed it is highlit in yellow.  In this case, regardless of how many times I click, reboot, etc, the highlight doesn't go away.  I find this annoying as I have a compulsive need to whack-a-mole any flags that my computers give me for updates (etc) and this one will. not. go. away.

I believe it is caused by: the installing technician originally did the install using the admin login while I was already logged in (if that makes sense).  This didn't take, so he had to log me out, then log himself in and do the install.  So perhaps there is some partial install somewhere that isn't getting "tripped" as being used.

Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not ask the help desk guy to fix it? :/

Comment: I could have him uninstall / reinstall, I suppose.  I had him log in as himself and open the program in hopes of clearing the notification, but that didn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable this feature entirely:

1. Right click on the start menu button and select properties
2. Select the `Start Menu` tab
3. Click the `Customize` button
4. Uncheck the `Highlight newly installed programs` checkbox
5. Press `OK`
6. Close the dialog

I don't think that there is a way to do this for just a single program though.

If you'd like a clumsy solution, that only kind of takes care of this, then just recreate the shortcut yourself and remove the folder added by the installer (in the Start Menu). Windows will not highlight manually created shortcuts.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only "solution" that shows in web search results.  It won't address my issue.

Comment: It will remove the highlight. I was under the impression that this **was** your issue. If you'd like a clumsy solution that only kind of takes care of this then just recreate the shortcut yourself and remove the folder added by the installer (in the Start Menu). Windows will not highligh manually created shortcuts.

Comment: It will remove the highlight, yes, but also prevent any future highlights from occurring, which I do not want.  And if the feature is ever turned back on then the highlight will return.  Now, your "clumsy solution" worked, for whatever reason.  If you put that as your answer then we're in business.

Comment: @n8 It's been done

Comment: @n8 ....for now...

Comment: There's always a java update.